# How to test the round trip latency of an SSH connection

Tags: ssh

I would like to test the latency of an SSH connection on a server behind a firewall for a few reasons:

1. I want to know the delay that is being added to all of my keystrokes
2. `<ssh time> - <ping time> = <ssh latency overhead>` would be nice to know.

I'm thinking something like: 
`ssh 'user@somehost' "ping parent"`

Answer (score 6):

So after googling for ssh round trip time instead of ping time, I found that the github project sshping does exactly what I want.

https://github.com/spook/sshping

The following serverfault question helped out
https://serverfault.com/questions/807910/measure-total-latency-of-ssh-session

Comment: metrix, are you able to include your command line usage of `sshping`?